# python - Mount EBS volume using boto3

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to use AWS Spot instances to train Neural Networks. To prevent loss of the model when the spot instance is terminated, I plan to create a snapshot of the EBS volume, make a new volume and attach it to a reserved instance. How can I mount, or make the EBS volume available using python & boto3.

These are the steps used to [make the volume available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) on Linux, but I want to automate the process so that I don't need to SSH into the instance every time. Here is the code I use to attach the volume -

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

spot = ec2.Instance('i-9a8f5082')
res = ec2.Instance('i-86e65a13')

snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId="vol-5315f7db", Description="testing spot instances")
volume = ec2.create_volume(SnapshotId=snapshot.id, AvailabilityZone='us-west-2a')
res.attach_volume(VolumeId="vol-5315f7db", Device='/dev/sdy')
snapshot.delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run mount command on instance. 2 way for it. One is the sending command with a ssh connection like @mootmoot wrote. The other one is the sending command with AWS SSM service like @Mark B wrote. Here is the detailed SSM solution sample, you can ignore unnecessary parts for you:

Send bash command to instances using AWS SSM:

```
# Amazon EC2 Systems Manager requires
# 1. An IAM role for EC2 instances that will process commands. There should be a system manager role and the instance should use this role ! (Did it while creation instance)
# 2. And a separate role for users executing commands. Aws IAM user that has access and secret keys should have ssm permission. (i.e. AmazonSSMFullAccess)
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-policies.html
def execute_commands_on_linux_instances(commands, instance_ids):
    client = boto3.client('ssm', **conn_args) # Need your credentials here

    all_ssm_enabled_instances, ssm_enabled_instances, not_worked_instances = [],[],[]
    not_worked_instances = instance_ids.copy()
    all_ssm_enabled_instances = list()
    outputs = list({})
    not_executed = list()

    # Select only the Instances that have an active ssm agent.
    if len(client.describe_instance_information()['InstanceInformationList']) > 0:
        resp = client.describe_instance_information(MaxResults=20)['InstanceInformationList']
        for ins in resp:
            all_ssm_enabled_instances.append(ins['InstanceId'])
        ssm_enabled_instances = list(set(all_ssm_enabled_instances).intersection(instance_ids))
        not_worked_instances = list(set(instance_ids).difference(all_ssm_enabled_instances))


        # Now, send the command !
        resp = client.send_command(
        DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript",
        Parameters={'commands': [commands]},
        InstanceIds=ssm_enabled_instances,
        )

        # get the command id generated by the send_command
        com_id = resp['Command']['CommandId']

        # Wait until all the commands status are out of Pending and InProgress
        list_comm = client.list_commands( CommandId=com_id)
        while True:
            list_comm = client.list_commands( CommandId=com_id)
            if (list_comm['Commands'][0]['Status'] == 'Pending'or list_comm['Commands'][0]['Status'] == 'InProgress'):
                continue
            else:
                # Commands on all Instances were executed
                break

        # Get the responses the instances gave to this command. (stdoutput and stderror)
        # Althoug the command could arrive to instance, if it couldn't be executed by the instance (response -1) it will ignore.
        for i in ssm_enabled_instances:
            resp2 = client.get_command_invocation(CommandId=com_id, InstanceId=i)
            if resp2['ResponseCode'] == -1:
                not_executed.append(i)
            else:
                outputs.append({'ins_id': i, 'stdout': resp2['StandardOutputContent'],
                            'stderr': resp2['StandardErrorContent']})

        # Remove the instance that couldn't execute the command ever, add it to not_worked_instances
        ssm_enabled_instances = list(set(ssm_enabled_instances).difference(not_executed))
        not_worked_instances.extend(not_executed)

        return ssm_enabled_instances, not_worked_instances, outputs
    else:
        print("There is no any available instance that has a worked SSM service!")
        return ssm_enabled_instances,  not_worked_instances, outputs
```

Create Instances with required IAM Instance profile that has required role that has required policy. As a result of this instance creation, instances have running SSM agents:

```
def create_ec2_instance(node_type):
    # define userdata to be run at instance launch

    userdata = """#cloud-config

    runcmd:
     - cd /tmp
     - sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
    """

    ec2_r = boto3.resource('ec2', **conn_args)

    rolename = "amazonec2ssmrole"
    i_pro_name = "ins_pro_for_ssm"

    # Create an iam instance profile and add required role to this instance profile.
    # Create a role and attach a policy to it if not exist.
    # Instances will have this role to build ssm (ec2 systems manager) connection.
    iam = boto3.resource('iam', **conn_args)

    try:
        response= iam.meta.client.get_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName=i_pro_name)
    except:
        iam.create_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName=i_pro_name)
    try:
        response = iam.meta.client.get_role(RoleName=rolename)
    except:
        iam.create_role(
                    AssumeRolePolicyDocument='{"Version":"2012-10-17","Statement":[{"Effect":"Allow","Principal":{"Service":["ec2.amazonaws.com"]},"Action":["sts:AssumeRole"]}]}',
                    RoleName=rolename)
        role = iam.Role(rolename)
        role.attach_policy(PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2RoleforSSM')
        iam.meta.client.add_role_to_instance_profile(InstanceProfileName=i_pro_name, RoleName=rolename)

    iam_ins_profile = {'Name': i_pro_name}

    if node_type == "Medium":
        instance = ec2_r.create_instances(
            ImageId='ami-aa5ebdd2',
            MinCount=1,
            MaxCount=1,
            UserData=userdata,
            InstanceType='t2.medium',
            KeyName=key_pair_name,
            IamInstanceProfile=iam_ins_profile,
            BlockDeviceMappings=[{"DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", "Ebs": {"VolumeSize": 20}}])
    elif node_type == "Micro":
        instance = ec2_r.create_instances(
            ImageId='ami-aa5ebdd2',
            MinCount=1,
            MaxCount=1,
            UserData=userdata,
            InstanceType='t2.micro',
            KeyName=key_pair_name,
            IamInstanceProfile=iam_ins_profile,
            BlockDeviceMappings=[{"DeviceName": "/dev/xvda", "Ebs": {"VolumeSize": 10}}])
    else:
        print("Node Type Error")
        return -1

    # Wait for the instance state, default --> one wait is 15 seconds, 40 attempts
    print('Waiting for instance {0} to switch to running state'.format(instance[0].id))
    waiter = ec2_r.meta.client.get_waiter('instance_running')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance[0].id])
    instance[0].reload()
    print('Instance is running, public IP: {0}'.format(instance[0].public_ip_address))

    return instance[0].id
```

Don't forget giving ssm permission. (i.e. AmazonSSMFullAccess) to the Aws IAM user that has access and secret keys.

By the way, conn_args can be defined as follows:

```
 conn_args = {
        'aws_access_key_id': Your_Access_Key,
        'aws_secret_access_key': Your_Secret_Key,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform those steps in the operating system. You can't perform those steps via the AWS API (Boto3). Your best bet is to script those steps and then kick off the script somehow via Boto3, possibly using the AWS SSM service.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with sending and execute ssh script remotely? Assume you are using ubuntu , i.e.

```
ssh -i  your.pem ubuntu@ec2_name_or_ip  'sudo bash -s' < mount_script.sh
```

If you attach tag to those resources, you can later use boto3 to inquired the resources by universal tag name, instead tied to the specific static id.